# How to convert Unix time to RFC-822 date-time using PHP

Tags: php, unix, timestamp

I have a unix timestamp like this one: **1323668326**.
I want to convert it to RFC-822 date-time, so I can use it in rss feed
I am new to PHP, so I would really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a [predefined constant](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php#datetime.constants.types) you can make use :-

```
date(DATE_RFC822, 1323668326);
```

Comment: i got the following error: ": date() expects parameter 2 to be long". I retrieve the timestamp from the mysql databse using sql

Comment: PHP treat numeric string as numeric too. I guess you are not using numeric string. Can you do a `var_dump(...);`

Comment: thx, it solved the problem, just that the time is not right (Wed, 31 Dec 69 19:00:00 -0500）, I guess it has something to do with the CMS I am using.